# ASPNET MVC2 ActionFilter Order attribute not accessible due to procetion level

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-2, actionfilterattribute, custom-action-filter

I'm trying to set Order attribute of ActionFilterAttribute in my ASP.NET MVC2 application.

```
<LoginFilterAttribute(Order = 1)> _
<AdminFilterAttribute(Order = 2)> _
```

Visual Studio intellicence tell me that Order property could be typed, but when I do that the compiler throw an error "Order is not declare. It may be inaccessible due to its procetion level."

What I can do to solve the problem ?

For my example I read and follow this article
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd381609.aspx

Answer (score 1):

That's the wrong VB.NET syntax. Give:

```
<LoginFilterAttribute(Order := 1)> _
<AdminFilterAttribute(Order := 2)> _
```

A try.

Comment: Thanks for help I copy and paste the example from MSDN and didn't think that Microsoft could post an incorrect syntax .... fantastic!

Comment: @user575380 - can you link to the page with the wrong syntax? I can probably get someone there to fix it.